# Что представляет из себя функция в c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я недавно ночью писал код и допустил ошибку. Мне нужно было записать в виртуальную память процесса указатель на нужную функцию. Делал я это так:

```
uint64_t *some_mapped_memory = ...;
some_mapped_memory[0] = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(myFunc);
```

Ошибка в том, что я не поставил `&` перед именем функции. И кастанулся не указатель, а "сама функция". Однако этот код работал так же, как и ожидалось.

Более того, позже я произвел тест:

```
#include <cstdio>

void f() {}

int main() {
    void (*fnc1)() = f;
    void (*fnc2)() = &f;
    printf("%p %p\n", f, &f);
    return 0;
}
```

Мало того, что `printf` вывел два одинаковые значения, так еще и код выше скомпилировался без проблем.

Я немного погуглил, но ничего не нашел по этому поводу. Честно говоря, нет под рукой `gcc` или вообще другого компилятора, тестировал с `visual c++`. Что по поводу моего кода думает стандарт? Ну обязано ли это работать на другом компиляторе, или валидным является только `&f`? И почему моя среда разработки показывает, что `fnc1` и `fnc2` оба являются `void(*)()`, однако `auto fnc3 = f` является `void()`?

В общем, то, что я показал - это какое-то злое умное преобразование, описанное стандартом, или же злое умное преобразование, которое может `visual c++`?

Comment: In each context, the name of an overloaded function **may be preceded by address-of operator &** and may be enclosed in a redundant set of parentheses. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address

Comment: @PetSerAl то, что вы скинули, скорее описывает операции, которые можно выполнять с именем функции. А вот почему так происходит я нашёл [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6893285/6716519). Я и думал примерно о том же (неявное преобразование функции к указателю на неё же). Но все же было интересно, как именно к данной ситуации относится стандарт...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имя функции (не функции-члена!) всегда может быть преобразовано в указатель на функцию, вне зависимости от наличия амперсанда перед именем функции.
Черновик C++17 [conv.func]:

> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the function.

Чуть больше про указатели на функции можно найти в моей [статье](http://scrutator.me/post/2016/03/30/pointers_demystified_p3.aspx#ptrs_and_funcs), хотя там нет ссылок на стандарт, т.к. рассчитана она на начальный уровень.

Comment: Хм, все же это стандартизировано... А вот такой вопрос: может ли это повлечь последствия в какой-нибудь ситуации?

Comment: @selya, «это» это что? Отсутствие амперсанда? Нет, не может.

Comment: ага. Ну, похоже на то. Отметил ответ. А как вы считаете, лучше ставить амперсанд? (Как хороший тон написания кода, что ли)

Comment: @selya, я ставлю, просто потому, что это явно выражает намерение.